# Who would win, a Young Red Dragon or a Behir?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

A Young Red Dragon and a Behir happen upon each other in the woods, and attack.

In the Monster Manual for Behir it says:

> Foes of the Dragons. In times long forgotten, giants and dragons engaged in seemingly endless war. Storm giants created the first behirs as weapons against the dragons, and behirs retain a natural hatred for dragonkind. A behir never makes its lair in an area it knows to be inhabited by a dragon. If a dragon attempts to establish a lair with in a few dozen miles of a behir's lair, the behir, is compelled to kill the dragon or drive it off. Only if the dragon proves too powerful to fight does a behir back down, seeking out a new lair site a great distance away.

Looking at their stats they seem very similar.

So who would win, and why?

---

Addendum:

The reason I ask this is because my players are going to be chased by a Behir, which they will inevitably hide from in a cavern. That cavern happens to have a dragon ritual being performed and if the players dont kill the dragon wyrmling then it will turn into a Young Red Dragon and leave the cavern.

At this point I think it would be interesting for plots sake that when the players leave the cavern they find the body of the Behir ravaged by the dragon (or maybe even vice versa) ((or maybe even a raging battle!))

Comment: Why would the dragon hang around? They're highly intelligent, and fighting a battle you have a decent chance of getting killed in when there's nothing at stake is not a highly intelligent thing to do.

Comment: There are too many factors to account for in this fight to simulate easily, especially considering the Dragon can fly and the Behir can only climb.

Comment: [Gorilla *versus* Shark!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/)

Comment: Ninja versus pirate ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a straight-up, white-room fight, the winner would be… it doesn't matter.

You want to have a behir body outside? That's fine, do it. Dragons and behir aren't a game of rock-paper-scissors — who would win depends on the situation, and individual specimens, which means that sometimes the dragon would win and sometimes the behir would win.

“Sometimes” is all you need to be able to justify a dragon-killed behir's body lying around.

Comment: This is of course the answer to any "who would win" question. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L4_zFYnnn2Y